# ASP Classic Performance Suggestions?

Tags: arrays, performance, function, asp-classic

I had to write a function that takes a value (qty) and then determines the range it falls in, and determines the price based off of that range.

So if 1-10 is passed in, the price is $2, if 11-20, the price is $4. Etc etc etc. And this had to be fairly unlimited, because this is being used on an eCommerce site to determine checkout shipping cost.

My question is if there is a more efficient way to do this, rather than having a loop to 10,000 that builds an array by 10's, and then loop through the array that I have made to determine the range of the value passed in.

```
function getPrice(qty)
    tempArray = array()
    for i = 0 to 10000 step 10
        addArrayItem tempArray,i
    next
    if qty > 9 then
        for i = 0 to ubound(tempArray)
            if cInt(qty) > tempArray(i) AND cInt(qty) <= tempArray(i+1) then
                response.write("falls in range " & tempArray(i) + 1 & " through " & tempArray(i+1) & "<br>")
                temp = left(tempArray(i+1),len(tempArray(i+1)) - 1)
                rate = formatcurrency(cInt(temp * 2),2)
                exit for
            end if
        next
    elseif qty > 0 then
        rate = "$2.00"
    else
        rate = "error"
    end if
    getPrice = rate
end function

sub addArrayItem(ByRef ar,ByVal count)
    ub = uBound(ar)
    reDim preserve ar(ub + 1)
    ar(ub+1) = count
end sub
```

Comment: Is it always the case that the price is equal to `floor(qty div 10) * 2`? If so....errr...there's your answer!

Comment: Wow. That in particular didn't work for me, but it let me on the right track to find what I was looking for, which was: -int(-qty/10) * 2 Sorry for the bad question, thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool - glad to help. I didn't post it as an answer because my VBScript is so rusty I didn't know the right function names ;-)